# Наличие/отсутствие cout меняет результаты вычислений программы

Tags: c++

Нужна помощь, я не очень силен в программировании, а тут в программе какая то совсем чертовщина творится. 
Проблема возникает в функции main (она в самом конце программы). В ней есть два цикла - в первом массив Weights инициализируется случайными числами от -5 до 5, во втором цикле значения этого массива присваиваются массиву Pweights, и выполняются некоторые другие действия. Очевидно что массивы Weights и Pweights должны быть идентичны. А проблема заключается в следующем: если раскомментировать вывод cout значений массива Weights в первом цикле, то все выводится как и должно - сначала значения массива Weights, затем значения массива Pweights, оба массива идентичны, заполнены случайными числами в нужном диапазоне. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если cout'ы в первом цикле закомментировать, начинаются странности. Значения Weights, выведенные ПОСЛЕ первого цикла все так же совпадают со значениями Pweights, но сами значения явственно теряют "случайность" - они располагаются уже таким образом что в каждом столбце числа одинаковы до второго знака после запятой. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Различия эти обусловлены только наличием cout внутри первого цикла: если он есть - значения во всех массивах правильные, если его нет - они располагаются в такой вот странной последовательности (а нужна именно последовательность случайных чисел!). Внутри самого cout никаких преобразований нет. 
Помогите пожалуйста, потому что я в тупике. Использовалась Visual Studio 2010.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#pragma warning(disable: 4305)
using namespace std;

float RandomNumber(int a, int b, int q, int seed)
{
    float s;
    srand(seed);

    if (q == 1) //нужен ли нам дробный промежуток
    {
        s = rand();
        s = s / 32767 * (b + 1) -
            b; //Если b = 0 то получаем несмещенный промежуток (0, 1), если b = 1 - то смещенный (-1, 1)
    }
    else
    {
        s = rand() % (a + 1); //При a=1000 получаем промежуток от 0 до 1000

        if (b == 1)
        {
            s = s - a / 2;
        }
    }

    return s;
}

int main()
{
    int i, seed, part;
    float r;
    float Weights[4][15];// Веса синаптических связей между нейронами

    for (part = 0; part < 4; part++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            seed = (i + 1) * clock() * time(NULL) + part;
            r = RandomNumber(1, 1, 1,
                             seed); //(верхняя граница, смещенный/несмещенный, дробный/целый, зерно)
            Weights[part][i] = r;
            //cout<<Weights[part][i]<<" ";
        }

        //cout<<endl;
    }

    //cout<<endl;

    for (part = 0; part < 4; part++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            cout << Weights[part][i] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сократите, пожалуйста, программу до состояния [mcve].

Comment: Обычно проблемы вида "от наличия/отсутствия вывода на экран меняется поведение" в C++ возникают при наличии undefined behavior (неопределённое поведение). Например, если где угодно есть какой угодно выход за границы массива или обращение к неинициализированной памяти - можно такое наблюдать в абсолютно любом месте программы.

Comment: @alexolut Сократил насколько возможно

Comment: @yeputons Индексы перепроверил уже раз по двадцать, со вчерашнего вечера сижу, снова и снова просматриваю код, ошибок не вижу ((

Comment: Еще раз изменил код, теперь проще уж точно некуда: функция main, в ней цикл в котором в другой функции вычисляется случайное число. Если выводить значения массива внутри цикла - все окей, так как и должно быть. Если вывести значения массива уже после завершения цикла - сохраняется все та же странность когда в каждом столбце значения отличаются на тысячные доли.

Comment: Причем если выводить значения массива и внутри цикла и после него то значения массива правильные. То есть они зависят от того есть ли cout внутри массива.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предполагаю, что это связано с использованием `seed`. Инициализировать ГСЧ для *каждого* числа - это как раз угробить его характеристики! Его нужно инициализировать один раз. Иначе вы теряете его качество...

Вывод притормаживает выполнение программы, и хоть немного, но меняется `clock()` - без вывода это будет *одно и то же значение*.

Закомментарьте `srand`

```
float RandomNumber(int a, int b, int q, int seed)
{
    float s;
    //srand(seed);
```

Внесите его сюда:

```
float Weights[4][15];// Веса синаптических связей между нейронами

seed=time(NULL);
srand(seed);
```

и посмотрите на результаты. Думаю, вы получите то, что хотели...

Comment: Спасибо, похоже дело было именно в этом!

Comment: Ну, если проблема решена, помечайте ответ как принятый...